# Getting error "TS2571: Object is of type 'unknown'" when trying to display object properties from a Firebase observable

Tags: angular, firebase, rxjs

I'm following along a tutorial that's at least 7 versions of Angular old. I anticipated having to work around deprecated code but I cannot find a recent example of how to do the same thing. I simply want to display the properties of the json object contained in the Observable.

Here is the code for **app.component.ts**:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    author$;

    constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
        this.author$ = db.object('/authors/1').valueChanges();
        
    }

}
```

In the markup,

```
<p>
    {{ (author$ | async).name }}
</p>
```

will produce the error in the title. If, however, I instead write:

```
<p>
    {{ author$ | async | json }}
</p>
```

the webpage will display the object completely:

> { "isPremium": true, "name": "Name Name", "students": 100 }

So how can I use interpolation to render specific content? I should probably also say that the tutorial was about using the "as" keyword to abbreviate this code to something like this:

```
<ul *ngIf="author$ | async as author">
    <li>{{ author.name }}</li>
    <li>{{ author.isPremium }}</li>
    <li>{{ author.students }}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it working by changing how I declared the author$ property. Formerly I declared it without a type. Now it works properly after declaring it like so:

```
export class AppComponent {
    author$: Observable<any>;
...
```

with the markup:

```
<ul *ngIf="author$ | async as author">
    <li>{{ author.name }}</li>
    <li>{{ author.isPremium }}</li>
    <li>{{ author.students }}</li>
</ul>
```

I should also note that the syntax offered by @ck706 also works if the property is declared correctly

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this should work with the unknown type. I'm assuming that Firebase returns an anonymous object. If it returns a JSON string, a JSON.parse() may need to be worked into the equation.

```
<ul *ngIf="author$ | async as author">
    <li>{{ author['name']}}</li>
    <li>{{ author['isPremium'] }}</li>
    <li>{{ author['students'] }}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get the same error. I tried setting a new property to JSON.parse('author$') and got "Argument of type 'Observable<unknown>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'." I may be conceptualizing Observables incorrectly